# Volume is outside the range

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-audio

My console log is throwing the following error:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'volume' property on
>   'HTMLMediaElement': The volume provided (1.005) is outside the range
>   [0, 1].

Can anyone explain this to me on how to fix this? Any help is appreciated! Thank you.

**Code:**

```
// Fade out/in functions for music player

function audio_fade_out(){
      var timer,
          myAudio = document.getElementById("musicPlayer");
      if (myAudio.volume > 0) {
          myAudio.volume -= 0.003;
          timer = setTimeout(audio_fade_out,0);
          console.log(myAudio.volume);
      }
  }

function audio_fade_in(){
      var timer,
          myAudio = document.getElementById("musicPlayer");
      if (myAudio.volume < $audio_volume) {
          myAudio.volume += 0.005;
          timer = setTimeout(audio_fade_in,10);
          console.log(myAudio.volume);
      }
  }
```

Comment: It's looks like you reached the maximum volume. put a condition to stop the timer in that point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `audio_fade_out()`, it's possible to get below `0`.  If `myAudio.volume` is `0.001`, this passes the test for `> 0`, and yet you still subtract `0.003` from it.

In `audio_fade_in()`, who knows because you didn't show us whatever `$audio_volume` is.

Following your method, what you would do is set the volume to be `Math.max(myAudioVolume - 0.003, 0)` to clamp whatever the value is to be at or above `0`.  Do the inverse on `audio_fade_in()`... `Math.min(myAudioVolume + 0.005, 1)`.

What you should *really* do however is use the Web Audio API and ramp the `gain` parameter of a `GainNode`.  That will sound much smoother.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioParam/exponentialRampToValueAtTime

Comment: Great feedback. Thank you Brad!